# Do you need to install a parser library? When it is already there

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, jupyter

I get this error when trying to parse html with beatufulsoup. I `pip3 install lxml` already. The package is there - `/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/lxml/` But I still get this error. Could anyone suggest what is wrong?

> FeatureNotFound: Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you
>   requested: xml. Do you need to install a parser library?

```
<ipython-input-22-0493a00ae0a0> in get_text(url)
     26 def get_text(url):
     27     r = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
---> 28     soup = BeautifulSoup(r, "lxml")
     29 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/bs4/__init__.py in __init__(self, markup, features, builder, parse_only, from_encoding, exclude_encodings, **kwargs)
    163                     "Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you "
    164                     "requested: %s. Do you need to install a parser library?"
--> 165                     % ",".join(features))
    166             builder = builder_class()
    167             if not (original_features == builder.NAME or

FeatureNotFound: Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: lxml. Do you need to install a parser library?
```